# MVC routing - actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say you have a given controller in .NET MVC, and a given folder in /VIEW/.
What is the best way to change views, if we have data and want to do i.e. a POST?
The two cases are:
Change the view to another view within the same view-folder.
Change the view to another view outside the view-folder.

What are your preferred methods?
I prefer something like @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index"), however this seems to only work within the same view-folder.

So one discrete question I have is, is it possible to use @html.actionlink to link to another controller?  Or is it only for links within the original controller?

Comment: There is a different overload of ActionLink method which allows you specify a different controller. Just look up the documentation in msdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So one discrete question I have is, is it possible to use
>   @html.actionlink to link to another controller? Or is it only for
>   links within the original controller?

**yes**, it is possible to use @html.actionlink to link to another controller. Kindly look at the below syntax.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    string protocol,
    string hostName,
    string fragment,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

So when you want to call an different controller, specify the controller name  next to action name.

Ex:

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index","Home")

or

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index","Manage")

Note: you can specify any controller name you want, and if dont specify the controller name and action name , then it will go to the current controller and action.

Hope the information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: good..:) And if you felt that was really helpful ,kindly accept it so that ,others also  will read it and get to know. Happy sharing and love coding Thanks Karthik..:)