# how to use @Html.ActionLink to show Index View with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

When I use `@ActionLink` with Index ActionName, this ActionName does not appear in the browser link.

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "return", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "NewsImages"
, routeValues: new { selectedNewsid = 1 }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

This action shows the following link on the browser:
**"http://localhost:23594/NewsImages/?selectedNewsid=1"**
but when I use another ActionName, the link shows properly!
What am I doing wrong? This is my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "GPTKish.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: but when i click on this created Link, site get error !!

Comment: also when i use : localhost:23594/NewsImages/index/selectedNewsid=1  site get error but when i use : localhost:23594/NewsImages/index?selectedNewsid=1 link work properly ........ where is wrong!!!! i confused !!

Comment: What kind of error exactly? And please show your route configuration, and your method signature

Comment: You can this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770516/mvc-routing-actionlink

Comment: We can't understand you, please write in English, thankyou

Comment: P.s. you still didn't tell us the error or show the method signature of your action method

Comment: i just want create link from NewsImages Controller and Index Action with SelectedNewsId Parameter... i Use below tag to resolve my problem : ..............  <a href="~/NewsImages/Index?selectedNewsid=@ViewBag.NewsIDen">Return</a>  .......

Comment: Index is by default omitted. Why would you want to show "Index" to users? It looks terrible. If you do want to, however, you'll have to remove Index as the default action

Comment: @Morteza Can you show us an example of when you use another ActionName, the link shows properly. What parameters are you passing there so that it is displaying correct. I believe your call is matching the wrong overload of the helper method.

Comment: @Camilo It does not matter whether the index is shown or not. But it's important that this address works correctly with this parameter With ActionLink

Comment: @Rahul when i change ActionName from Index to for Example Index2 ActionLink Work Properly but when use  Index ActionLink show Wrong path withOut parameter that set on it ...

Comment: @Morteza In your `ActionLink` change `new { selectedNewsid = 1 }` to `new { id= 1 }` .If you specifcially want `selectedNewsid ` as your parameter then you would have to define a new rule for it. And place that rule before the default rule otherwise it won't be picked up.

Comment: @Rahul I'm totally disappointed with this ridiculous ActionLink, and I use the A tag instead... thank u bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gave the name of action or id in ActionLink similar to default name maintained in routes.MapRoute then it invisible in URL and it create sometimes problems.
If you want to use Index as action name then just add / before Index

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "return", actionName: "/Index", controllerName: "NewsImages"
    , routeValues: new { SelectedNewsid = 1 }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

(PS: In demo, I change controller name to Home)

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHPSqB)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in wrong in your above code 
please remove "/" before "?" from your URL and try with  below link
Example : "http://localhost:23594/NewsImages?selectedNewsid=1"

Comment: thank you . i know that but @Html.ActionLink Create this link Automatically.

Comment: Yes. and  "Index"  method is default Action so it will not be visible on URL

Comment: all thing good and ok but why when click on this link export of my ActionLink like this : localhost:23594/NewsImages!!!!!   where is ActionName:Index and Parameters:selectedNewsId]

Comment: If you use the give cshtml code for Link then your link will be "http://localhost:23594/NewsImages?selectedNewsid=1"
here NewsImages:Controller Name,
selectedNewsid : Parameter Name and 
Index : Action will not be visible because it is default action

Comment: @Govind can you edit your answer, remove what you wrote (that doesn't make sense) and write your comments there? The only answer for this question is: it works like this by default, there's nothing wrong. Your comments are correct, the answer is not

Answer (score -1):

Create a new route

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "NewsImages", url: "{controller}/{action}/{selectedNewsid}", defaults: new { controller = "NewsImages", action = "Index",selectedNewsid= UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new[] { "GPTKish.Controllers" } );
```

then the proper link will be:
http://localhost:23594/NewsImages/1

Please adjust the code, this is the pattern for MVC url.